# Keep Alive control don't work first time

Tags: xpages

I have used the Keep-Alive control of Upgrade Pack 1, and I have this problem.

"After your first login to the application the control inside the Xpages don't work.

But if you open another Xpages and return to the fisrt Work "

Someone know this Bug?

Comment: look into domlog.nsf what is exact url syntax generated by control. maybe there is bad url in address bar right after first login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens when there's a load time of more than 30 seconds.  I.e.

1. Page initiates load - which initiates the time variables.
2. Page load takes MORE than 30 seconds because of dojo - yes this still happens in the real world.
3. Timer kicks in AFTER page load.
4. The the ping happens too late

More simply, the ping happens at this interval:...  (PAGE LOAD TIME + SESSION TIMEOUT VALUE) - 30 Seconds.

To ensure this doesn't happen where I use it, I've adjusted the delay time from 30 secs to 5mins:

```
    <xe:keepSessionAlive>
        <xe:this.delay><![CDATA[#{javascript:
try{
  var delay:int=facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false).getMaxInactiveInterval()-300;
  if(delay>0){
    return delay ;
  }
}catch(e){}
return ; // failover to default}]]></xe:this.delay>
    </xe:keepSessionAlive>
```

It sure would be good if the control took the page load time in to account though :)

Answer (score 1):

That should work. The xe:keepSessionAlive does just as says it keeps the session alive until the browser page is closed. It can be added to the XPage and no further configuration is necessary. It will ping the server 30 seconds before the session ends by default. You can also change this time by setting the 'delay' property to a number of seconds. 
We'll probably need to know more detail on your scenario though in a scenario I tried (the control is on a default page that opens an existing document in edit mode) it all works as expected.

Comment: Hi Paul, I don't know because..but if you inspect the traffic with firebug you see the problem.
I have insert the layout CCcontrol into all my Xpage.

Only and repeat..only the first lauch page for the first time don't trigger the PING...but if you go in another page work...
Or if you press SHIFT+RELOAD work..but the first time after login don't work the PING of Keep-Alive control